# Export into a copied file

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-excel

I will first tell you what I want to do, maybe that makes finding a solution easier. I want to export a file (after changing it) into a file that uses macro buttons etc on it's own. The problem is I cant delete said file.

My current solution is as follows: I use a "open file" Dialog so the user tells me the Excel that should be used as a template. VBA then should copy this file (the destination is once again given by a save file dialog) and then delete the used range in the new file and copy the values in this new file.

So there are 3 files Involved.

- A: Current file with changed data and the macro I am doing right now.
- B: Template File with macros.
- C: New File that should be created with the macros from B and the
  Data from A

So far I have this code that opens B and and copies it (i guess) it. My primary issue is how do I access the newly created file now. I assume I can somehow store it as a variable. Something like `X = Path the user just selected in the save file dialog`?
The deleting and inserting Data afterwards should be rather simple I guess/hope.

I hope you guys can help me and thanks a lot in advance :)

Here is my code so far:

```
Dim StandardPfad As String
Dim ExportBlatt As Worksheet
Dim NeueDatei As Workbook


StandardPfad = "C:\XYZ"

'   ExportBlatt = Worksheets("Blatt1")

Set NeueDatei = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blatt1").Copy Before:=NeueDatei.Sheets(1)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets(2).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

' displays the save file dialog
StandardPfad = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
        "Exceldateien (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Vorlagen Datei auswählen", _
        InitialFileName:="")

NeueDatei.SaveCopyAs Filename:="C:\Test\CopyBook.xls" 'Hier Speicherort angeben

NeueDatei.Close savechanges:=False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either I`m missing something in your question, or... Isn't this `StandardPfad` enough?

It needs a bit more error handling if the user cancel's the selection, but that's your `X = Path the user just selected in the save file dialog`

```
' displays the save file dialog
StandardPfad = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
    "Exceldateien (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Vorlagen Datei auswählen", _
    InitialFileName:="")

NeueDatei.SaveCopyAs Filename:=StandardPfad
```

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the late response. Not quiet, so far the "B" file is missing so i cant select the file that contains the macros. Maybe this description is a little bit easier: 

Select a file Z, copy the whole file (so that all macros are copied as well), delete all Worksheets from it but one (SheetX).


Copy sheetY from my current File A and paste it into sheetX.

Save the Copy of File Z as File Z_1.


Right now i save my sheetY from my current file into a new one but I need the macros from File Z in it.